# RC4 cipher is no longer supported on Internet Explorer in Windows 7 OS How to get support for IE in Windows 7

Tags: internet-explorer

I have taken below ref:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/3151631/rc4-cipher-is-no-longer-supported-in-internet-explorer-11-or-microsoft

**Method 1: Internet Options settings**
I have enabled all the options specified
1)I have turn on SSL3 in  Internet Explorer through settings, 
Start Internet Explorer.
Go to Internet Options > Advanced > Settings > Security > Use SSL 3.0.

**Method 2: Registry Editor**

1) Start Registry Editor to modify the registry entry:
2) Locate and then select the following registry entry:
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
    On the Edit menu, point to New, and then click DWORD Value
    Type SecureProtocols, and then press Enter.
3) Change the current SecureProtocols value by setting the fifth bit to 1.

*I have tried all the options specified in the ref, but no use.*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the easy fix in the article? Download the file and let it fix for you.

Besides, why do you want to support the outdated RC4 cipher? It has several weaknesses which can be used to attack the encryption itself. Therefore the general security recommendation is to disable RC4 ciphers at all.

You should enable TLS 1.2 in your services and remove support for RC4. You could refer to [this article](https://msrc-blog.microsoft.com/2013/11/12/security-advisory-2868725-recommendation-to-disable-rc4/) for more security advisory.

Comment: 1) I have tried an easy fix mentioned in the ref, but no luck. 2) Our server supports only RC4 CipherSuite so mandatory to have a support in even in IE

Comment: I can reproduce the issue in win7. Maybe that's due to the different IE 11 versions. You could try to check if you can update the IE 11 to the latest version in win7. But the solution in the article mentions win10 and win8.1 not win7, so maybe that's not for win7. I didn't find other solutions either. Or you could try to check if you can delete the cumulative security update for IE in win7.